# How to check whether an rdn exists in LDAP or not using java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I created a role with following rdn:

```
erglobalid=3224285689051620393,ou=roles,erglobalid=00000000000000000000,ou=org,dc=com
```

I deleted the above role

Now the above rdn does not exists in LDAP.

but i want to check whether it exists or not in LDAP? is there any method such in for this?

I checked with `search()` and `lookup()` methods, but these methods are throwing exceptions,.. Because of whcih according to requirement of my application I have to write code in catch block which is not ideal

can someone please help me with this

Comment: That's a DN (Distinguished Name), not an RDN (Relative Distinguished Name). The RDN part of that is `erglobalid=3224285689051620393`. If you deleted this entry, it is deleted: hard to see why you would want to check. If the deletion failed, an exception would have been thrown. A `Context.lookup("erglobalid=3224285689051620393,ou=roles,erglobalid=00000000000000000000,ou=org,dc=com")` will confirm, by failing. 'Not ideal' is just a state of mind. The method is designed to throw an exception, and you should catch it.

Comment: I dont want to check whether deletion failed , I have list of dns in one array and want to remove those dn's that are not part of the ldap

Comment: If you don't want to check it why are you asking about how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

> I created a role with following rdn:

```
erglobalid=3224285689051620393,ou=roles,erglobalid=00000000000000000000,ou=org,dc=com
```

No you didn't. That is a DN (Distinguished Name), not an RDN (Relative Distinguished Name). The RDN part of that is `erglobalid=3224285689051620393.`

> I deleted the above role

Good for you.

> Now the above rdn does not exists in LDAP.

The above *DN* doesn't exist in LDAP.

> I want to check whether it exists or not in LDAP?

It doesn't. You deleted it. If the delete had failed it would have thrown an exception. If it didn't fail, it's deleted, so it doesn't exist.

> is there any method such in for this?

Yes, there are `search()` and `lookup()` methods.

> I checked with `search()` and `lookup()` methods, but these methods are throwing exceptions ... Because of which according to requirement of my application I have to write code in catch block

Correct.

> which is not ideal

Which is the way those APIs are designed. Bad luck. There is nothing you can do about it. NB `search()` doesn't throw an exception if nothing matches: it returns an empty enumeration of `SearchResult`.

I imagine what you're *really* asking about is checking for existence *before* deletion. This also is a bad idea: it causes two lookups at the server instead of one, and twice as much network traffic, or more ... and it suffers from a timing window problem: it might exist when you test and not exist when you delete, or, worse, it might not exist when you test but exist when you delete, or when you would have deleted. Don't do this. Don't think like this. Deletion is an atomic operation that will fail if the entry doesn't exist. That is exactly what you want.